# Having issues trying to make fixed navigation bar mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

i'm working on FCC Technical Documentation Page and i'm having an issue, i'm trying to make this project mobile responsive, but i'm running into an issue where I can't seem to figure out how to move my left fixed nav bar and transition it to a top nav bar that is center aligned at anything below 920px, if you can be of any help I would appreciate it. I will link the project below so anyone can look at the code.

EDIT **Finished making the project mobile responsive, might not be the most efficient method but it worked as i'm learning, click the link to view the code to see what I did that worked.**

https://codepen.io/ochovj/pen/eYvwmYr

```
@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  .nav-ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: center; 
    float: none;
  }

}
    

/* End of Responsiveness  */

/* Nav Bar Container */
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%; 

    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make your navbar list `display: flex` at the desired breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 920px) { 
  .nav-ul {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
   }
}
```

`display: flex` alone should do roughly what you want, but `flex-wrap: wrap` allows multiple rows if your elements don't all fit on a single line and `justify-content: center` will center the `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` parent.

The list elements will need more styling, like padding, as they'll just be squished in a row together -- but this will quickly fix your position issue.